# Enumeration: "cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers"

Tags: swift

I can't initialize an enumeration using the rawValue initializer. Any thoughts? Error commented below:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play
// Xcode Version 7.3 (7D175)

import UIKit

enum Theme {
    case Default, Dark, Graphical
}

let possibleTheme = Theme(rawValue: 1) 
// Error: 'Theme' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers.
```

Comment: The enum has no raw type, you need to add `enum Theme : Int`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
enum Theme: Int {
    case Default, Dark, Graphical
}

let possibleTheme = Theme(rawValue: 1) // Dark
```

An enum doesn't have a raw value unless you specify its type. Possible raw value types are `String`, `Character` and any of the number types. [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html)

Comment: Ok, this is a valid answer, but what's the point of it though? Why would you construct an enum with an int? Why care what is backed by in this particular case. Can only lead to trouble.

Comment: That totally depends on OP's project. Sometimes it can be very handy to create an `enum` from an `Int` if, say, you have a `UISegmentedControl`.

Comment: Honestly, just working through a tutorial for UIAppearance. https://www.raywenderlich.com/108766/uiappearance-tutorial

Comment: Hi Ryan, did you ever get this to work? I'm working on the same tutorial and ran into this problem. But, since the enum is returning a UIColor, I'm not sure how to get this to work because, as @TimVermeulen points out, raw values types can only be String, Character, and numbers types.